# Make a pointer to an object in the constructor C++

Tags: c++, object, pointers, constructor

I would like to know how to make a pointer to a newly created object in the constructor in c++?

What is the address of a class?

```
class MyClass
{
    public:
};

class MyClass2
{
    public:
    //I need a pointer to the created object
    MyClass2 *pObjectName;

    //Constructor
    MyClass2()
    {
        pObjectName = &//I have no clue how to get the adress of the (not yet) created object.
    }
};

int main()
{
    //The way it works
    //Makes Object
    MyClass *pObject;
    MyClass Object;
    //pObject points to Object
    pObject = &Object;
    //Prints adress of Object
    printf("%p", pObject);


    //The way I would like to see it work
    MyClass2 Object2;
    //Prints adress of Object
    printf("%p", Object2.pObjectName);

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would be:

```
MyClass2()
{
    pObjectName = this;
}
```

But you do not need to do that. A `this` pointer is implicitly passed to each non-static member function of a class.

Answer (score 2):

Inside the class you can access the pointer to the object with `this`. This pointer is defined and passed implicitly inside every instance method. Therefore you don't really need to memorize it into another variable.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use `this`, e.g:

```
MyClass2()
{
  pObjectName = this;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not say:

```
MyClass object;
printf("%p", &object);
```

Comment: Because I won't use it for just the printf function ;). Thanks alot though!

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve.